# How to seperate your read and write queries in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

I have created 2 replicas of my master DB and now I need all the read queries to go to the replicas and the write queries to the master DB.

I need to know whether there is any way to do this at the infrastructure level? Or really any way that does not involve identifying every read operation manually because in a large codebase that would be very unfeasible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you're using AWS RDS service, there are two endpoints -writer for master and reader for read-replica. You can use both the endpoints in the application and redirect all the read calls to read-replica but the write call made in the master will not immediately appear in the read-replica it is not synchornous.

Comment: Thankyou ! But my question is how will Java know where reads or writes are being performed ? Will I need to add some annotations above methods that involve read/write from DB ?